# Plumbing question adding a filter pipe diameter concerns

Tags: plumbing

I am going to be adding a whole house filter to my water plumbing.   I am on well water.  I have 1 1/4" pipe coming from the pump going to the filter however the inlet for the filter in only 3/4".  After the filter i would go back to the 1 1/4" to the pressure tanks then to the house main supply lines.

Will the pipe size change for the filter cause issues? Or should i put tge filter after the pressure tanks?

Answer (score 1):

The systems I've worked on have the filter between the tanks and the house supply line. You don't want to restrict the flow from the pump. what size is your house supply line?

Comment: Although I put them in where it is easiest I do like them after the pressure tank isolation valve, this way I can close the valve drain the pressure change the filter and open the valve without messing with the pump. There should be a disconnect close but not always. If I can my favorite is to isolate both after the tank and after the filter this way there is only the pressure in the filter to bleed off. +